# MVC4 - Linq Lambda expression to query multiple association tables

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

Am trying to create a cascading drop down and have been following this tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/85ed7a/cascading-dropdown-list-with-mvc-linq-to-sql-and-ajax//)

My database is more complex than the one in the tutorial and I need help with creating a lambda expression

Here are my database tables

[image: DB Tables]

The cascading drop down I want to create, will allow a user to select a 
RiskType and then depending on the selection will display the associated GroupMembers for the selected RiskType.

Here is the code I have in my controller

```
public ActionResult AddNewRisk()
        {
            ViewBag.RiskTypeID = new SelectList(_DBContext.RiskTypes, "ID", "Description");
            ViewBag.GroupMembers = new SelectList(new List<GroupMember>(), "ID", "Name");
            return View();
        }


public IList<GroupMember> GetGroupMember(int SelectedRiskTypeID)
        {
            return   _DBContext
                     .RiskTypeHasGroups

        }

        public JsonResult GetJsonGroupMember(int ID)
        {
            var GroupMemberListT = this.GetGroupMember(Convert.ToInt32(ID));
            var GroupMemberList = GroupMemberListT.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                                   {
                                       Text = x.Name,
                                       Value = x.ID.ToString()
                                   });
            return Json(GroupMemberList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

It's in the method named GetGroupMember that am having trouble and don't know how to write the correct lambda expression in order to pull back only the group members which have a matching RiskGroup.ID followed by a matching RiskType.ID. If anyone could show me the correct way to do this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the ID field from the RiskTypeHasGroup table, set the primary key to RiskTypeID,RiskGroupID, and rebuild your model. Do the same for RiskGroupHasGroupType.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Am guessing I don't need ID's on association tables since they are redundant, Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct, and it also makes a mess of the model if you do.  Once removed, if you use the built in model builder, then the association tables just get removed from the model automagically.  Your RaidGroup class will have a RiskTypes property, and your RiskType class will have a RaidGroups property so you can easily navigate from one to the other.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the model is simplified as I suggested, then your query becomes:

```
public IQueryable<GroupMember> GetGroupMember(int SelectedRiskTypeID)
{
  return _DBContext.GroupMembers
    .Where(g=>g.RiskGroups.Any(rg=>rg.ID=SelectedRiskTypeID));
}
```

If you decide to keep the IDs, then this would be your query:

```
public IQueryable<GroupMember> GetGroupMember(int SelectedRiskTypeID)
{
  return _DBContext.GroupMembers
    .Where(gm=>gm.RiskGroupHasGroupTypes
      .Any(rghgt=>rghg‌​t.RiskGroup.ID==SelectedRiskGroupTypeID))
}
```

Comment: I'll give what you have suggested a shot although it's actually the GroupMembers am trying to get, but I will still need to find out what RiskGroups have what GroupMembers and what RiskTypes have what RiskGroups.

Comment: @BruceYoungblood Updated answer for the new GetGroupMember function.

Comment: Thanks for the help Robert

Comment: No problem.  It helps to start down the right path, and having a good model to start with will make everything 10x easier for you.

Comment: Are there any circumstance when it would be appropriate to actually keep an association table in the model? If so how would you access it in a simlar situation to mine. I was able to access them previously using something like this  'code'ViewModel.Controls = _DBContext
                                        .ThreatHasControl
                                        .Include("ThreatHasControl.Control")
                                        .Where(x => x.ThreatID == ThreatID)
                                        .Select(x => x.Control);'code'

Comment: If it is just for association, no, you will never need it.  However, if you do need something beyond just a simple association (like a sort order), then yes.  But it'll add another layer in your model between the two.

Comment: You also never need to use Include to reference things while in the IQueryable.  All properties, no matter how deeply nested are always accessible.  You only need the Include if you want to return something other than the base.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the query if you decide to keep the ID field (or add another field beyond the associated keys).

Comment: Thanks again, that's great am still quite raw so I'll have to apply this in my code then debug etc to fully grasp whats going on. Really appreciate the help and lesson.